# FilePulse Source Connector on aws msk - TimeoutException

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am currently trying to use FilePulse Source Connector but keep getting these errors

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=fetchMetadata,.... 
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting to send the call. Call: fetchMetadata
```

Comment: It would be great if you showed the full stacktrace. Error indicates your bootstrap-servers are incorrect

Comment: @OneCricketeer Sorry I actually progressed further with lenses plugin, will post nother question on that

Comment: I'm having this same problem @cvk, did you get any sense of what was happening with FilePulse or your other settings?